# How to write a SFDC formula to find if a date is within a date range

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, admin

I need to have a boolean formula to see if TODAY() is between two other date fields.

e.g. datefield_1__c <= TODAY() >= datefield_2__c

I've tried writing this a number of ways and cannot get SFDC to play nice with me.
One example below:

```
IF( 
(
(TEXT(MONTH(datefield_1__c)),
TEXT(DAY(datefield_1__c)),
TEXT(YEAR(datefield_1__c)))
<=
(TEXT(MONTH(TODAY())),
TEXT(DAY(TODAY())),
TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())))
>=
(TEXT(MONTH(datefield_2__c)),
TEXT(DAY(datefield_2__c)),
TEXT(YEAR(datefield_2__c)))
),
TRUE, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Dates and Datetimes can be compared as-is with the normal comparison operators

So all you need to do here is 2 comparisons

And `IF(<conditions>, true, false)` can *always* be simplified to just be `<conditions>`.

So with that, you're looking for

```
AND(
    TODAY() >= Date_Field_1__c,
    TODAY() <= Date_Field_2__c
)
```